# Javascript Push out Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a menu that comes out from the side of the screen but it just overlaps the content on the page. I need it to reduce the main content size or to sqeeze/push it.

Hopefully this is enough code for you to understand. My project is huge so I cant post all the code

I want my menu to behave like the right push menu here: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Help").click(function() {
        var $body = $("#sliderMenu");
        $body.animate({
            right: parseInt($body.css("right"), 10) == 0 ? -($("#sliderBody").outerWidth()) : 0
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#sliderMenu
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:-360px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}


#sliderBody
{
    float:right;
    top:0px;
    width:349px;
    background:#333333;
    border-left: 2px solid #00B463;
    border-top: 2px solid #00B463;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    color: White ;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: can you add your html and css and post a fiddle?

Comment: This is not a PHP, don't use `$` as a variable prefix. Just `body` instead `$body`. And that css & html would help us help you.

Comment: @JanSpurny A `$` variable prefix is valid in JavaScript. Often used by users for readability, to differentiate between JavaScript variables and jQuery objects.